# Remove this header column from Python. No idea where it comes from

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the csv file and I am trying to make the date as the index column. However, this "international visitor arrivals statistics" can't be removed!!! How do I remove this annoying header? I have no idea how it got there and how to remove it.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data5 = pd.read_csv('visitor.csv', parse_dates = [0], index_col=[0])

#data5 = data5.drop([0,1,2], axis = 0) # delete rows with irrelevant data
data5.columns = data5.iloc[3] # set the new header row with the proper header 
data5 = data5[4:7768] # Take remaining data less the irrelevant data and the header row

data5
```

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Na9t9.png)

[Original excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSF8x.png)

Comment: If possible, remove it from the excel before you load it

Comment: Can you not just pass `skiprows=4` to your `read_csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the header parameter in pd.read_csv which sets the row you want to use as your header in your df so for you, you would want to use the 5th row so you'd set the header=4 like this:

```
data5 = pd.read_csv('visitor.csv', parse_dates = [0], index_col=[0], header=4)
```